# Why does my TaskLoader only stores the last data?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, asynctaskloader

I am having problem with the flow of my code. Please please please help :(

Okay, so the flow goes like this. the first Activity loads the `recyclerview`which stores the `ArrayList`data. The data of the `Arraylist` consist of information about a `Premise` which it retrieve from an `API` of a website. It uses `GET` method.

Okay, next when I select an item from the `recyclerview`, it brings me to the `next Activity` which I will enter an `integer`. Then, as it returns to the `first Activity`, it passes the `integer` value and the `index` of the `recyclerview` item. The `recyclerview` updates the item with the `index` and stores the `integer` value in the item.

So, my problem is: when I repeat the process of selecting an item from the `recyclerview` and enter an integer, the first activity only stores the latest data. the previous item is gone.

Where on Earth did I did wrong? I am new to mobile app development. Please help. I am beyond clueless.

Here's the first Activity. It's called MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Premise>> {

    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

    private LoaderManager loaderManager;
    private RecyclerView rcvPremises;
    private EditText premiseSearch;

    String pTrackVisitor_s, pPosition_s, pPremiseName, pLocation;
    int pTrackVisitor, pPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loaderManager = LoaderManager.getInstance(this);
        premiseSearch = findViewById(R.id.search);
        rcvPremises = findViewById(R.id.rcvPremise);

        Intent mainIntent = getIntent();
        pTrackVisitor_s = mainIntent.getStringExtra("trackVisitor");
        pPosition_s = mainIntent.getStringExtra("position");

        if (pTrackVisitor_s != null) {
            pTrackVisitor = Integer.parseInt(pTrackVisitor_s);
            pPosition = Integer.parseInt(pPosition_s);
        } else {
                pTrackVisitor = 0;
                pPosition = 0;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<Premise>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        return new PremisesListTaskLoader(this, pTrackVisitor, pPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<ArrayList<Premise>> loader, ArrayList<Premise> vPremise) {
        loaderManager.destroyLoader(0);

        if (!vPremise.isEmpty()) {

            rcvPremises.setAdapter(new PremiseAdapter(this, vPremise));
            rcvPremises.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            premiseSearchBar(premiseSearch, vPremise);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load data from iiotisme.com", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<ArrayList<Premise>> loader) {
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more parts of the coding. I 'll share them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not read data in `onCreate`, it will be only triggered when Activity is created first time, I assume your activity will be resume, it should use something like `onActivityResult`. You should start second activity using `startActivityForResult` and in `onActivityResult`, you will get an `intent` from where you can read the latest data every time.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data == null) 
            return;
        pTrackVisitor_s = data.getStringExtra("trackVisitor");
        pPosition_s = data.getStringExtra("position");

        if (pTrackVisitor_s != null) {
            pTrackVisitor = Integer.parseInt(pTrackVisitor_s);
            pPosition = Integer.parseInt(pPosition_s);
        } else {
            pTrackVisitor = 0;
            pPosition = 0;
        }
    }
```

You can pass the `index` and other required data to your second activity using `intent` like below

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("position", <yourClickedIndex>);
startActivityForResult(1234, SecondActivity.class);
```